# creating a new rails project in rails 2.2.2 (while having rails3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, installation

In my computer (linux - ubuntu) I have installed rails 2.2.2 and rails 3

Now i want to create a project in rails 2.2.2. (Like rails ). But it asks to enter the rails command as in rails 3 (like rails new )

when i type rails -v it shows the rails version as 3. But in my gem list it has both rails 2.2.2 and 3

how can i create a project in rails 2.2.2

thanks in advance

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking if you have two versions of ruby and rails installed the last one will be the "normal" one using "normal" commands like:

```
ruby
rails
gem
```

For all the other versions you can define (or have defined during installation) some aliases like:

```
ruby187
rails222
gem222
```

Another solution could be [this](http://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2008/03/12/using-multiple-versions-of-rails/)

Or the best solution I recommend for working with multiple ruby and rails versions is [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)

Comment: Hi tommasop, your first link has the trik . It should be as rails _<version>_ projectname. (Ex rails _2.2.2_ projectname
).... thanks a lot

Comment: glad to be of help on this issue!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. Create a rails project.

```
rails myproject
```

Go to your envirnonment file and modify to

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.2.2' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

EDIT

Yes , Sorry about that .This method may have worked in rails versions < 3. My Bad ! RVM the way to go.

Should do the trick. Also I recommend you update to atleast Rails 2.3.9, in case you don't want to start off with Rails 3.

Comment: Wouldn't this use the generators to generate a rails 3 application? Even if you set the RAILS_GEM_VERSION back to 2.2.2 you'd still have all the generated rails 3 framework.

Comment: Hi Shreyas, as Shadwell says it will generate the rails3 frame work. But before that it doesn't allow me to use rails <project name> and it force me to enter it in the rails3 way (rails new <project name>) which i dont want to do - cheers sameera

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 easiest ways how to manage it:

0) remove not used version of rails

1) rails is just simple command, so each time when you need to run special version of it you can specify full full path to it( or alias it one time)

2) if you strongly need to have different types/versions of ruby environments( and/or different versions of ruby gems such as rails), I recomend you to use [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) - it is the most easiest way to manage it.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to specifically use one version of your installed version for a specific project use

```
rails _2.2.2_ (your project)
```